# Determine if a VBComponent regards a workbook or a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The following code allows me to go through the workbook and worksheets that have macros:

```
For Each VBCmp In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    Msgbox VBCmp.Name
    Msgbox VBcmp.Type
Next VBCmp
```

As [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445236(v=vs.60).aspx) shows, for a workbook and a sheet, their type are both `100`, ie, `vbext_ct_Document`. But I still want to distinguish them: I want to know which `VBCmp` is about a workbook, which one is about a worksheet.

Note that `VBCmp.Name` can be changed, they are not necessarily always `ThisWorkbook` or `Sheet1`, so it is not a reliable information for what I am after.

Does anyone know if there exists a property about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worksheet objects and Workbook objects both have a CodeName property which will match the VBCmp.Name property, so you can compare the two for a match.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim vbcmp
    For Each vbcmp In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        Debug.Print vbcmp.Name, vbcmp.Type, _
                    IIf(vbcmp.Name = ActiveWorkbook.CodeName, "Workbook", "")
    Next vbcmp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I'm using to deal with exported code (VBComponent's method) where I add a prefix to the name of the resulting file.

I'm working on an application that will rewrite, among other statements, API declares, from 32 to 64 bits. I'm planning to abandon XL 32 bits definitely. After exportation I know from where did the codes came from, so I'll rewrite them and put back on the Workbook.

```
Function fnGetDocumentTypePrefix(ByRef oVBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent) As String
    'ALeXceL@Gmail.com
    Dim strWB_Date1904 As String
    Dim strWS_EnableCalculation As String
    Dim strChrt_PlotBy As String
    Dim strFRM_Cycle As String

    On Error Resume Next
    strWB_Date1904 = oVBComp.Properties("Date1904")
    strWS_EnableCalculation = oVBComp.Properties("EnableCalculation")
    strChrt_PlotBy = oVBComp.Properties("PlotBy")
    strFRM_Cycle = oVBComp.Properties("Cycle")

    If strWB_Date1904 <> "" Then
        fnGetDocumentTypePrefix = "WB_"
    ElseIf strWS_EnableCalculation <> "" Then
        fnGetDocumentTypePrefix = "WS_"
    ElseIf strChrt_PlotBy <> "" Then
        fnGetDocumentTypePrefix = "CH_"
    ElseIf strFRM_Cycle <> "" Then
        fnGetDocumentTypePrefix = "FR_"
    Else
        Stop    'This isn't expected to happen...
    End If

End Function
```